# What does it mean to connect to a certain port?

Tags: service, ssh, connection, port

For example, when you make an ssh connection, you are connected to port 22. What happens then? On a very high level brief overview, I know that if port 22 is open on the other end and if you can authenticate to it as a certain user, then you get a shell on that machine.

But I don't understand how ports tie into this model of services and connections to different services from remote machines? Why is there a need for so many specific ports running specific services? And what exactly happens when you try to connect to a port?

I hope this question isn't too confusing due to my naive understanding. Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)

Comment: Each service listens to a different port - only one process may listen to any particular port. Think of a port as a personal mailbox number in an apartment complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP-IP ports on your machine are essentially a mechanism to get messages to the right endpoints.

Each of the possible 65536 ports (16 total bits) fall under certain categories as [designated](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) by the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA).

> But I don't understand how ports tie into this model of services and
> connections to different services from remote machines? Why is there a
> need for so many specific ports running specific services?
>
> ...
>
> And what exactly happens when you try to connect to a port?

Think of it this way: How many applications on your computer communicate with other machines? Web browser, e-mail client, SSH client, online games, etc. Not to mention all of the stuff running under the hood.

Now think: how many *physical* ports do you have on your machine? Most desktop machines have one. Occasionally two or three. If a single application had to take complete control over your network interface nothing else would be able to use it! So TCP ports are a way of turning 1 connection into 65536 connections.

> For example, when you make an ssh connection, you are connected to
> port 22. What happens then?

Think of it like sending a package. Your SSH client in front of you needs to send information to a process running on the other machine. So you supply the destination address in the form of "user@[ip or hostname]" (so that it knows which machine on the network to send it to), and "port 22" (so it gets to the right application running on the machine). Your application then packs up a TCP parcel and stamps a destination and a return address and sends it to the network.

The network finds the destination computer and delivers the package. So now it's at the right machine, but it still needs to get to the right application. What do you think would happen if your SSH packet got delivered to an e-mail client? That's what the port number is for. It effectively tells your computer's local TCP mailman where to make the final delivery. Then the application does whatever it needs to with the data (such as verify authentication) and sends a response packet using your machine's return address. The back and forth continues as long as the connection is active.

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

Imagine your server as a house with 65536 doors. If you want to visit family "HTTP", you go to door 80. If you were to visit family "SMTP", you would visit door no. 25.

Technically, a port is just one of multiple possible endpoints for outgoing/incomming connections. Many of the port numbers are assigned to certain services [by convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

Opening/establishing a connection means (when the transport protocol is TCP, which are most of the “classical” services like HTTP, SMTP, etc.) that you are performing a [TCP handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking). With UDP (used for things like streaming and VoIP), there's no handshake.

Unless you want to understand the deeper voodoo of IP networks, you could just say, that's about it. Nothing overly special.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to get some intuition about the voodoo of IP networks, but your explanation about how TCP and UDP relate to this kind of fits a piece of the puzzle for me. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to experiment a bit, install wireshark and look what's happening when you open a website or retrieve e-mail or connect to a FTP server. Pro tip: try using services without encryption and without compression, and you will even see the payload.

Answer (score 1):

The port is meant to allow applications on TCP/IP to exchange data. Each machine on the internet has one single address which is its IP. The port allows different applications on one machine to send and receive data with multiple servers on the network/internet. Common application like ftp and http servers communicate on default ports like 21 and 80 unless network administrators change those default ports for security reasons